# How to disable the color change of item in ListBox when the mouse on the item ?

Tags: silverlight

I have simple ListBox with some objects. 
When the mouse is on some object the object background color is change.

Is it possible to avoid this color change with out disable the object ? 
( this object contain button that must to be enable )

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've supposed that you don't want to highlight a list box item container when the mouse is over it. But maybe the "object" is a some kind of a different control, so the information about its type would be important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the visual state animation from the ListBoxItem template.
The default template can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

The style without mouseover background looks so:

```
<Style x:Key="IgnoreMouseOverItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
  <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
              <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                  <vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                              <!--<Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".35"/>
                              </Storyboard>-->
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".55" />
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".75"/>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                      <vsm:VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                              <Storyboard>
                                  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Duration="0">
                                      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                          <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                              <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                          </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                          </vsm:VisualState>
                          <vsm:VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                      </vsm:VisualStateGroup>
                  </vsm:VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                  <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                  <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Opacity="0" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1"/>
                  <ContentPresenter
                          x:Name="contentPresenter"
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                  <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" />
              </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then apply the new style to the ListBox

```
<ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource IgnoreMouseOverItem}" />
```

Comment: Just missing the tag </Style> ;-)

Comment: @user2056563 What exactly do you want and why did you post a link to the same page that we are now?

Comment: @vorrtex i am sorry i will delete that comment, i needed your help on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578128/list-box-with-multiple-data-template-style-for-selected-item

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to avoid highlighting, you can use ItemsControl.